# Php replace exact mach split

Tags: php, arrays

I have tried php replace but it changes all occurance. I want exact mach only and split | and +

```
$menu='home|about|product+service+able|contact|ab|';

echo str_replace("ab","book",$menu);
```

Result:

```
$result ='home|about|product+service+abel|contact|book|';
```

Or
If example 2

```
$menu2='home|about|product+service+ab|contact|able|';
```

Result2

```
$result ='home|about|product+service+book|contact|able|';
```

Comment: did you simply try `str_replace("|ab|","|book|",$menu);` ? (On the other hand, what is the relationship of your question with arrays ?)

Comment: Some time ab comes inside + {home|about|product+service+able+ab|contact|}

Comment: A simple solution would be to use [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) with '|' as seperator and then check the whole string if its ab and then replace it and then combine the array again via [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) with '|' seperator.

Comment: Split | and + my question expload | and + how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use regular expression to catch 'ab' the the beginning and end of the string https://www.php.net/manual/ro/function.preg-replace.php
see code below with some testcases

```
<?php
$menu='home|about|product+service+able|contact|ab|';
$menu1='home|about|product+service+able|contact|ab';
$menu2='ab|about|product+service+able|contact|abx|';
$menu3='home|ab|product+service+able|contact|abx';
$menu4='home|about|product+service+ab|contact|able|';

$pattern = array('/^ab([|+])/', '/([|+])ab([|+])/', '/([|+])ab$/');
$replacement = array('book${1}', '${1}book${2}', '${1}book');

echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $menu);
echo "\n";

echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $menu1);
echo "\n";

echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $menu2);
echo "\n";

echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $menu3);
echo "\n";

echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $menu4);
echo "\n";

?>
```

output

```
home|about|product+service+able|contact|book|
home|about|product+service+able|contact|book
book|about|product+service+able|contact|abx|
home|book|product+service+able|contact|abx
home|about|product+service+book|contact|able|
```

Comment: Did u checked example 2 it have + cant change

Comment: @Denekew You said you want to change exact "ab", for me it means to to be between "|" chars or between begin/end of the string and "|".
You can provide a differ example and expected output.

Comment: I said split | and + my question u only solve |

Comment: Code updated to consider also "+" as separator

Comment: @Denekew see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68464627/php-replace-exact-mach-split/68467981#68467981) on how.

Comment: @Marcel Preda can u add delete menu take the correct position eg  `home|about|product+service+able|contact|book|` delete `about` or `service` result `home|product+able|contact|book|` if you can update code thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since no one offered a non-regex solution, here is mine:

```
<?php
// Some Configuration
$searchFor = 'ab';
$replaceWith = 'book';

// Sample data
$menu = 'home|about|product+service+able|contact|ab|';

// Actual code
$array = explode('|', $menu);
$resultArray = [];
foreach ($array as $string) {
    if ($string === $searchFor) {
        $resultArray[] = $replaceWith;
    } else {
        $resultArray[] = $string;
    }
}
$result = implode('|', $resultArray);

echo $result;
// home|about|product+service+able|contact|book|
```

You could make some optimizations, but for easier understanding i left it as it is.

Update:
If you also want to be able to split between `+` too use the following.

```
<?php
function customSplit($var, $searchFor, $replaceWith) {
    $array = explode('|', $var);
    $resultArray = [];
    foreach ($array as $string) {
        $tmpResult = [];
        foreach (explode('+', $string) as $tmpString) {
            if ($tmpString === $searchFor) {
                $tmpResult[] = $replaceWith;
            } else {
                $tmpResult[] = $tmpString;
            }
        }
        $resultArray[] = implode('+', $tmpResult);
    }
    return implode('|', $resultArray);
}

// Some Configuration
$searchFor = 'ab';
$replaceWith = 'book';

// Sample data
$menu = 'home|about|product+service+able|contact|ab|';
$menu2 = 'home|about|product+service+ab|contact|able|';

echo customSplit($menu, $searchFor, $replaceWith);
// home|about|product+service+able|contact|book|

echo customSplit($menu2, $searchFor, $replaceWith);
// home|about|product+service+book|contact|able|
```

Comment: you code not work for Example2 `$menu='home|about|product+service+ab|contact|able|';`

Comment: @BerlikTradingplc You're right! I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Look for any `ab` **not** preceded or followed by a character in the range `a-z`.

So you need a negative lookbehind for a-z : `(?<![a-z])`

and a negative look ahead for a-z : `(?![a-z])`

with `ab` in the middle

regex: `(?<![a-z])ab(?![a-z])`

[Here is an example](https://regex101.com/r/g8diCF/1/)

And in php:

```
$pattern = '/(?<![a-z])ab(?![a-z])/';
$result  = preg_replace($pattern,'book',$yourstring);
```

Answer (score 0):

function make more easier

```
function replace_match($find, $replace, $menu)
{
    $pattern = array('/^'.$find.'([|+])/', '/([|+])'.$find.'([|+])/', '/([|+])'.$find.'$/');
    $replacement = array($replace.'${1}', '${1}'.$replace.'${2}', '${1}'.$replace); 
    return preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $menu);
}

echo replace_match('ab','book',$menu);
```